# Creating a linked list of notes from a Phrase (Jmusic)

Tags: java, linked-list

I have this constructor that takes in a phrase of `jmusic` notes, and I'm trying to set each individual note to an individual node in a linked list of `SoloNodes` which hold one individual note only. most of the methods in that constructor I've written myself but they're pretty self explanatory. What exactly must I do to make this generate a linked list?

```
public Solo(Phrase myPhrase)
{

    int length=myPhrase.length();
    head=new SoloNode();
    SoloNode next=new SoloNode();
    for(int i=1; i<=length;i++)
    {
       head.setNote(myPhrase.getNote(i));
       next=head.copyNode();
       head.setNext(next);
       head=next;
       i++;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that's the code you are looking for:

```
private SoloNode head;

public Solo(Phrase myPhrase)
{
    int length = myPhrase.length();
    SoloNode node = new SoloNode();
    head = node;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        node.setNote(myPhrase.getNote(i));
        if (i + 1 < length) {
            node.setNext(new SoloNode());
            node = node.getNext();
        }
    }
}
```

I assumed you are using a class SoloNode which looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068240/linked-lists-unable-to-add-random-amount-of-nodes-to-end-of-list).

I assumed too that `myPhrase.getNote(i)` starts with index 0 (not 1) because that is the common way how it works in Java.

After you run this code the SoloNodes are filled with data from myPhrase and linked from one to next. With `getNext()` you can navigate from current to next. Only for last SoloNode it will return `null`.